# C# sockets fail to reconnect

Tags: c#, windows, sockets

I have problem which I was trying to solve for some time now, still with no success.
We have simple server client app, which works by synchronously exchanging messages.

Here is related code.

Creating sockets:

```
Socket sender;

IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(remoteHost);                
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, remotePort);
sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
sender.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
sender.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
sender.Connect(remoteEP);
```

Receiving data:

```
try {
if (!sender.Connected)
    Reconnect();
int bytesRec = sender.Receive(readBuffer);

if (bytesRec == 0)
{
   //warning 0 bytes received
}
return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRec);
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
   //print se.ErrorCode
   throw;
}
```

Sending data:

```
try {
if (!sender.Connected)
    Reconnect();

byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMessage + "\0");

int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

return true;
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
   //print se.ErrorCode
   throw;
}
```

Reconnect code:

```
if (sender != null)
{
    if (sender.Connected)
    {
        sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        sender.Disconnect(true);
    }

    sender.Close();

    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(RemoteHost);
    IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, RemotePort);
    sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sender.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
    sender.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

    sender.Connect(remoteEP);
}
```

Here is what is happening:

While receiving the data I get 10060 error code, which means it timed out. So I try to reconnect.
Then it keeps throwing the same error code for some time with the following exception:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond n.n.n.n:x

Then eventually it manages to "reconnect" but receives 0 bytes.
So I try to send some data. It starts failing with WSAECONNABORTED 10053 error.
I again try to reconnect.
It continues with 10053 error and receiving 0 bytes.
It never recovers.

So I close the app, start it again, but it cannot connect, server logs say that there are to many opened connections. Problem is that server doesn't see that the client has disconnected...

I am a bit lost here.
Please help!

Comment: 1. What do you have in the code for `//warning 0 bytes received` in real ? 2. Try sniffing the network using wireshark.

Answer (score 2):

What I think should solve your problem is change as below:

> When there is no bytes received and you have set a Socket.ReceiveTimeout and Socket.SendTimeout to good value as required by Socker server/client (may be check manual for purposes what you are using this, generally it is 1 to 5 minutes), Then disconnect the socket and create a new connection. As it denotes as **RST** - Reset or something like orphaned connection (TCP protocol term) from the other end i.e. telling to reconnect back.

### Receive data

```
try
{
    if (!sender.Connected)
       Reconnect();

    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(readBuffer);    
    if (bytesRec == 0)
    {
        //warning 0 bytes received and some logging
        // Reconnect code here or function calling to reconnect
        Reconnect();
    }
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRec);
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
   //print se.ErrorCode
   throw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, added the changes will see how it behaves.

Comment: @Tadzys have you got your solution?

Comment: After the changes were made, there haven't been any disconnects, so do not know yet.